# How to display a stream of list from a bloc using a listview

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bloc

I am working on an instant messaging application, and I need the user to send and receive messages in real-time. I am using Firebase as the app backend, `flutter_bloc` package to manage states, and streams to send and receive messages in real-time.

I have successfully implemented the send message functionality, and I am able to retrieve the messages successfully from Cloud Firestore, but when the user sends a message it is not loaded into the chat messages `ListView`.

This is the implementation of the `ChatProvider` `getCurrentChatMessages()` method that is called in the `ChatBloc`.

```dart
  Stream<List<ChatMessage>> getCurrentChatMessages() {
    return this.messagesRef.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
    .snapshots()
    .map((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents.map<ChatMessage>((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => ChatMessage.fromFirestore(snapshot)).toList();
    });
  }
```

In the `ChatProvider`, these are the methods that propagate the list of chat messages to the UI

```dart
  Stream<ChatState> mapFetchCurrentChatMessagesEventToState(FetchCurrentChatMessagesEvent event) async* {
    yield FetchingCurrentChatMessagesState();
    final bool chatExists = await _chatProvider.chatExists;
    // If chat does not exists create chat.
    if (!chatExists) {
      await _chatProvider.createChat();
    }
    _chatProvider.getCurrentChatMessages().listen((List<ChatMessage> chatMessages) {
      print('Chat messages length: ${chatMessages.length}');
      dispatch(FetchedCurrentChatMessagesEvent(chatMessages));
    });
  }

  Stream<ChatState> mapFetchedCurrentChatMessagesEventToState(FetchedCurrentChatMessagesEvent event) async* {
    final List<ChatMessage> chatMessages = event.chatMessages;
    yield FetchedCurrentChatMessagesState(chatMessages);
  }
```

This is the `ListView` that displays the chat messages.

```dart
class ChatMessagesList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatMessagesListState createState() => _ChatMessagesListState();
}

class _ChatMessagesListState extends State<ChatMessagesList> {
  List<ChatMessage> _chatMessages = List<ChatMessage>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: BlocBuilder<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
        condition: (ChatState oldState, ChatState newState) => oldState.hashCode != newState.hashCode,
        builder: (BuildContext context, ChatState state) {
          if (state is FetchingCurrentChatMessagesState) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          if (state is FetchedCurrentChatMessagesState) {
            _chatMessages = state.chatMessages;
          }

          if (_chatMessages.length == 0) {
            return Container();
          }

          print('Chat Messages:\n$_chatMessages');

          return ListView.builder(
            reverse: true,
            itemCount: _chatMessages.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final ChatMessage chatMessage = _chatMessages[index];
              return ChatMessageTile(
                chatMessage: chatMessage,
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever, a message is sent, the `ChatBloc` sends the updated chat messages list to the `ChatMessagesList` widget, but the widget fails to update accordingly. It only displays the first element in the `_chatMessages` list, not until I `pop`, and `push` the route, that is when I get to see the updated list.

I want the chat messages list to be updated with the sent message when the user clicks on the send message button.

Answer (score 0):

Using rxdart's package streamcontrollers e.g BehaviourSubject you can consume your list 
Example in the bloc class:

```
final _list = BehaviourSubject<List<ChatMessage>>(); //private variable
Observable<List<ChatMessage>> get list => _list.stream; //exposesvariable_publicly

exampleMethod(){ 
//prepare your list and when ready load the stream using sink
_list.sink.add(readylist);
}
```

Now on your listview use streambuilder

```
Widget _listView(){
 return StreamBuilder(){
   stream: blocProvider.list
   builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ChatMessage>> listSnapShot){
     //custom build your UI now with data in listSnapshot.data.

   }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. The `bloc` actually gets the list populated. But the problem lies in when I want to display it in the `ListView`, it keeps displaying the first element in the list, until I `pop`, and `push` the route, that is when I get the full elements in the list displayed.

Comment: Hello, I have tried your solution, but the problem still persists, the `ChatBloc` sends the chat messages to the `ChatListWidget`, but the `ListView`, fails to update its children with the new chat messages.